# Using a subclass of AuthorizeAttribute in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm trying to modify the [Authorize] tag for Controller methods in MVC. I found an example that many claimed to be working. This is the code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizeRedirect : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string IS_AUTHORIZED = "isAuthorized";

    public string RedirectUrl = "~/error/unauthorized";

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        httpContext.Items.Add(IS_AUTHORIZED, isAuthorized);

        return isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        var isAuthorized = filterContext.HttpContext.Items[IS_AUTHORIZED] != null
            ? Convert.ToBoolean(filterContext.HttpContext.Items[IS_AUTHORIZED])
            : false;

        if (!isAuthorized && filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(RedirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

I added this code as a Class inside of my HomeController class, and added the tag to a method:

```
 [AuthorizeRedirect]
public ActionResult Devices()
{
    return View();
}
```

When i try to go as unAuthorized to the Devices view i don't get redirected to /error/unauthorized.
I get redirected to the regular account/login with a returnurl parameter.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `error/unauthorized` action require authentication?

Comment: Yeah, i assume the AuthorizeRedirect tag makes the action require authentication?

Comment: I think there's some confusion. I mean, does that action have the `AuthorizeRedirect` attribute on it?

Comment: Yes, the action has the AuthorizeRedirect attribute

Comment: So you auth attribtue redirects to this action which also has the attribute attached. Take it off that action and try it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code: 
base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);